# How to make $S^n$ 's n on the leftside?

Tags: math-mode

As we know we can use below way to write the power of a R,

```
$R^n$
```

but how can I make it on the left ?

my requirement comes from there:
[image]

Comment: Do give `${}^n\!R$` a try. I must confess to not actually being able to spot this math formula anywhere in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: Am I blind? Where in that image are there any superscript on the left of a variable?